# Get icon image from any files

Tags: java, icons

I can get icon from a file with this code. But, it's 16x16 size. And, I need bigger than.

```
 Icon icon = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(new File("c:/Program/Captain.exe"));
```

Afterwards, I found this code, but I can't find APIs. I see this error : "ShellFolder is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release"

```
 File file = new File("c:/Program/Captain.exe");
 ShellFolder sf = ShellFolder.getShellFolder(file);
 Icon icon = new ImageIcon(sf.getIcon(true));
```

Could you plese help me.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: is `Captain.exe` an image? Because it does have any image extension but rather a windows executable extension. Any reason, maybe am lost.

Comment: No, this is an example, not image file. I mean, I try to get it "exe" file icon.